# pass updated data in FlatList with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I run a graphql query and use the results to render some items. This works fine. Now on another screen, I run another mutation using apollos refetch option, such that whenever that mutation is run, the first query will refetch data every where it is being used. The refetching part works fine and I have tested it on other screens.

However, since I am doing some mappings and use setStates, although I get the new data, it is not passed to the `FlatList` so the FlatList doesn't get updated. On another screen where I am not doing mappings, I am simply passing `data` into the `FlatList` and it works well but here, it doesn't.

So how can I fix this? I tried using `useEffect`but I don't know what to write inside it.

```
export const WhitelistBar: React.FC = () => {
  const [friendList, setFriendList] = useState<Friend[]>();
  const [originatorId, setOriginatorId] = useState<number>();

  useEffect(() => {
    //setFriendList(DATA);
    //console.log('friendlist', friendList);
  }, [useGetMyProfileQuery]);
  
  const _onCompleted = (data) => {
    console.log('running', data);
    let DATA = data.me.friends.nodes.map(
      (item: {
        id: number;
        firstName: string;
        rating: number;
        vehicles: Vehicle[];
        friends: UserConnection;
      }) => ({
        id: item.id,
        imageUrl: defaultUrl,
        name: item.firstName,
        rating: item.rating,
        vehicles: item.vehicles,
        numberOfFriends: item.friends.totalCount,      
      }),
    );
    setFriendList(DATA);
    console.log('daattaaa', DATA);
    setOriginatorId(data.me.id)
  };

  const _onError = () => {
    let DATA = [
      {
        id: 1,
        imageUrl: defaultUrl,
        name: 'Friend',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        imageUrl: defaultUrl,
        name: 'Friend',
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        imageUrl: defaultUrl,
        name: 'Friend',
      },
    ];
    setFriendList(DATA);
    setOriginatorId(0);
  };

  const { data } = useGetMyProfileQuery({
    onCompleted: _onCompleted,
    onError: _onError,
  });

  return (
    <View style={scaledStyles.container}>
      <View style={scaledStyles.whiteListBarTitle}>
        <Text style={scaledStyles.whiteListBarText}>Meine Freunde</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <FlatList
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          data={friendList}
          horizontal={true}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <WhitelistItem
              title={item.name}
              face={item.imageUrl}
              numberOfFriends={item.numberOfFriends}
              vehicles={item.vehicles}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you post the code to codesandbox so that the issue is better reproducible

Comment: I'll have to integrate api details for the queries and unfortunately, I am not supposed to do that due t@RaghvenderKataria

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're calling your useGetMyProfileQuery function on every render?

From what I can tell, you want to move that function call into the useEffect like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
    useGetMyProfileQuery({onCompleted: _onCompleted, onError: _onError});
}, [])
```

This will run useGetMyProfileQuery once when the component mounts, similar to how componentDidMount works!

Not sure if that's what you're after though!

Comment: This gives me an invalid hook call error. useGetMyProfileQuery is a custom graphql hook. I want to re-render it every time because the data might be changed at the backend